# How do functions that simultaneously operate over vectors and their elements work in R?

Tags: r

Take the following example:

```
boltzmann <- function(x, t=0.1) { exp(x/t) / sum(exp(x/t)) }
z=rnorm(10,mean=1,sd=0.5)
exp(z[1]/t)/sum(exp(z/t))
[1] 0.0006599707
boltzmann(z)[1]
[1] 0.0006599707
```

It appears that `exp` in the `boltzmann` function operates over elements and vectors and knows when to do the right thing. Is the `sum` "unrolling" the input vector and applying the expression on the values? Can someone explain how this works in R?

Edit: Thank you for all of the comments, clarification, and patience with an R n00b. In summary, the reason this works was not immediately obvious to me coming from other languages. Take python for example. You would first compute the sum and then compute the value for each element in the vector.

```
denom = sum([exp(v / t) for v in x])
vals = [exp(v / t) / denom for v in x]
```

Whereas is R the `sum(exp(x/t))` can be computed inline.

Comment: I don't really understand this question, mostly since I'm not sure what you expected to happen. (Incidentally, note that there is not really such thing as an "element" in R- a number is just a vector of length one. For instance, try `x = 2; print(x[1]); print(x[1][1])`).

Comment: @DavidRobinson sorry, I'm new to R. Another way to describe this is that in the numerator, x is treated element by element and in the denominator it is aggregated over to produce the sum. How is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be clearer if you evaluated the numerator and the denominator separately:

```
x = rnorm(10,mean=1,sd=0.5)
t = .1
exp(x/t)
# [1] 1.845179e+05 6.679273e+03 4.379369e+06 1.852623e+06 9.960374e+02
# [6] 1.359676e+09 6.154045e+03 1.777027e+01 1.070003e+04 6.217397e+04
sum(exp(x/t))
# [1] 2984044296
```

Since the numerator is a vector of length 10, and the denominator is a vector of length 1, the division returns a vector of length 10.

Since you're interested in comparing this to Python, imagine the two following rules were added to Python (incidentally, these are similar to the usage of arrays in `numpy`):

1. If you divide a list by a number, it will divide all items in the list by the number:

   ```
   [2, 4, 6, 8] / 2
   # [1, 2, 3, 4]
   ```
2. The function `exp` in Python is "vectorized", which means that when it is applied to a list it will apply to each item in the list. However, sum still works the way you expect it to.

   ```
   exp([1, 2, 3]) => [exp(1), exp(2), exp(3)]
   ```

In that case, imagine how this code would be evaluated in Python:

```
t = .1
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
exp(x/t) / sum(exp(x/t))
```

It would follow the following simplifications, using those two simple rules:

```
exp([v / t for v in x]) / sum(exp([v / t for v in x]))
[exp(v / t) for v in x] / sum([exp(v / t) for v in x])
```

Now do you see how it knows the difference?

Comment: Thanks, this makes the most sense to me as an explanation. It is still a bit of a mystery how R knows to treat the x in the differently than the x in the numerator. Is the sum computed once or for each element in x?

Comment: @drsnyder: The reason is that `sum` isn't vectorized, while `exp` is. `sum` thus works on the full vector, not on each element. (How could `sum` be computed once for each element in `x`? That would be keeping the vector exactly the same- not a very useful function.)

Comment: @drsnyder: Put another way- what do you expect the result of `sum(1:5)` to be? Do you expect it to be `15`, or `c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` (because that's the "sum" of each single element)?

Comment: I expected `sum()` to return the sum. However, being new to R, I found it surprising that in the numerator (in this case) x is treated element wise while at the same time being summed in the denominator. For example if you did this in another language, you would have to compute the sum first and then iterate using the value computed by the sum (unless you wanted to compute it again on each iteration).

Comment: @drsnyder: It has absolutely nothing to do with the fact that it's in the numerator or the denominator. `sum` always returns the sum of a vector, and `exp` will always be applied to each element in the vector.

Comment: For example `z = sum([exp(v / t) for v in x]); vals = [exp(v / t) / z for v in x];` in Python.

Comment: I think I might understand your issue- you might be forgetting that `x` is a vector when the expression `exp(x/t) / sum(exp(x/t))` is evaluated. The numerator then becomes a vector of length 10, and the denominator becomes a vector of length 1. A vector of length 10 divided by a vector of length 1 becomes a vector of length 10.

Comment: @drsnyder: I give an example of "translating" this to Python in my edited answer.

Comment: Yes! Makes more sense now. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This is explained in [An Introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html), [Section 2.2: Vector arithmetic](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#index-Recycling-rule-19).

> Vectors can be used in arithmetic expressions, in which case the
>   operations are performed element by element. Vectors occurring in the
>   same expression need not all be of the same length. If they are not,
>   the value of the expression is a vector with the same length as the
>   longest vector which occurs in the expression. Shorter vectors in the
>   expression are *recycled* as often as need be (perhaps fractionally)
>   until they match the length of the longest vector. In particular a
>   constant is simply repeated. So with the above assignments the command
>
> ```
> x <- c(10.4, 5.6, 3.1, 6.4, 21.7)
> y <- c(x, 0, x)
> v <- 2*x + y + 1
> ```
>
> generates a new vector v of length 11 constructed by adding together,
>   element by element, 2*x repeated 2.2 times, y repeated just once, and
>   1 repeated 11 times.

Comment: This doesn't explain what is happening with `sum` in the function though. In the numerator, x is treated element by element but in the denominator, it is iterated over to compute the sum.

Comment: @drsnyder: That doesn't make sense. `x` isn't treated differently.  `x/t` returns a vector because `t` is recycled along `x`. `exp` returns a vector as well.  `sum` returns a vector with length=1, which is then recycled along the the numerator, the same as `x/t` was.

Comment: It makes sense to you, but not immediately to me coming from other languages :). It is unusual to have a value magically recycled. See also my comments below to David.

Comment: @drsnyder: I agree recycling values is unusual; that's why I referred you to the section on recycling in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

Vectorisation has several slightly different meanings in R.

It can mean accepting a vector input, transforming each element, and returning a vector (like `exp` does).

It can also mean accepting a vector input and calculating some summary statistic, then returning a scalar value (like `mean` does).

`sum` conforms to the second behaviour, but also has a third vectorisation behaviour, where it will create a summary statistic across inputs.  Try `sum(1, 2:3, 4:6)`, for example.